# dx-file uploader is not working inside dx-data-grid(Angular ,T.S.)dev extreme version 21.2.5 file uploader is not, angular version 13.2

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme-angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD7Ie.png)

IN my data grid inside in angular type script  file uploader is not working inside data grid.. I am using dev extreme for data-grid...but when i put my file-uploader container ouside the data grid it is working but when i put inside data grid it is not working..

i want my file uploader to work inside dx-data-grid

my file tab component html

```
<div id="data-grid-demo">
  <dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    keyExpr="ID"
    [showBorders]="true"
  >
    <dxo-paging [enabled]="false"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-editing
      mode="form"
      [allowUpdating]="true"
      [allowAdding]="true"
      [allowDeleting]="true"
    >
    </dxo-editing>
    <dxi-column dataField="Prefix" caption="Title" [width]="70"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="FirstName"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="LastName"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Position" [width]="170"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="StateID" caption="State" [width]="125">
      <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="states" displayExpr="Name" valueExpr="ID">
      </dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="BirthDate" dataType="date"> </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Notes" [visible]="false">
      <dxo-form-item
        [colSpan]="2"
        editorType="dxTextArea"
        [editorOptions]="{ height: 100 }"
      >
      </dxo-form-item>
    </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column>
      <dxo-form-item>
        <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="image/*" />
      </dxo-form-item>
    </dxi-column>
    
  </dx-data-grid>
</div>
```

tab component.ts type srcipt file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  ActivatedRoute,Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonService } from 'src/app/shared/services/common.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import notify from 'devextreme/ui/notify';



interface Employee {
  ID: number;
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
  Prefix: string;
  Position: string;
  Picture: string;
  BirthDate: string;
  HireDate: string;
  Notes: string;
  Address: string;
  StateID: number;
}

interface State {
  ID: number;
  Name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabe',
  templateUrl: './tabe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabe.component.scss']
})
export class TabeComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: any=[];
  uploadedFiles: string[] = [];

  employees: Employee[] = [{
    // Employee objects here
    ID: 1,
    FirstName: 'John',
    LastName: 'Heart',
    Prefix: 'Mr.',
    Position: 'CEO',
    Picture: 'images/employees/01.png',
    BirthDate: '1964/03/16',
    HireDate: '1995/01/15',
    Notes: 'John has been in the Audio/Video industry since 1990. He has led DevAv as its CEO since 2003.\r\n\r\nWhen not working hard as the CEO, John loves to golf and bowl. He once bowled a perfect game of 300.',
    Address: '351 S Hill St.',
    StateID: 5,
  }];

  states: State[] = [{
    // State objects here
    ID: 1,
    Name: 'Alabama',
  }, {
    ID: 2,
    Name: 'Alaska',
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    Name: 'Arizona',
  }, {
    ID: 4,
    Name: 'Arkansas',
  }, {
    ID: 5,
    Name: 'California',
  }, {
    ID: 6,
    Name: 'Colorado',
  }, {
    ID: 7,
    Name: 'Connecticut',
  }];

  isEditing = false;
  formData: Employee = {
    ID: 0,
    FirstName: '',
    LastName: '',
    Prefix: '',
    Position: '',
    Picture: '',
    BirthDate: '',
    HireDate: '',
    Notes: '',
    Address: '',
    StateID: 0,
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Your initialization logic here
  }
  

  onFileSelected(event: any): void {
    // Handle file selection event here
    this.uploadedFiles = event.value; // Store the uploaded files in your component property
  }

  // Event handler for form submission (if needed)
  getEmployees() {
    return this.employees;
  }

  getStates() {
    return this.states;
  }

 
  
}
```

Comment: I already tried dx-file-uploader is also not working

Comment: <div id="fileuploader-container"  caption="uploadMode">
    <dx-file-uploader
      selectButtonText="Select File"
      labelText="uploadMode"
      accept="*"
      uploadMode="useForm"
      (onValueChanged)="onFileSelected($event)"
    >
    </dx-file-uploader>
  </div>  it is also not working